# Can't Boot Windows after BackTrack 5 install

Tags: windows-7, linux, boot, installation, bootloader

My computer won't allow me to boot into Windows 7 after I installed BackTrack 5 (A Linux Distro). I don't believe this is a boot sector problem because, as you will see in the [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SwyIUCtPEQc), the Windows bootloader is working, but Windows won't load. It freezes at AtiPcie64.sys when it loads. I removed AtiPcie64.sys from the drivers folder then there was a problem with ClassPNP.sys. I just copied and pasted the driver in hopes that the Windows default VGA driver would kick in. *I know now have AtiPcie64.sys back in drivers folder.

***I need help diagnosing and fixing this problem.*** I'd rather not format any partitions, if able.

Extra Info:
When I use diskpart (from the Installation USB) I get invalid dynamic disk. However, the partition managers show that my disk is a Basic disk.

Windows attempts to boot into Safe Mode.

Last known config and restore point don't work.

I'm on a dual boot with Kali Linux, a Debian based Linux, installed.

Automatic Repair doesn't detect Windows, even when Windows bootloader is enabled and Grub disabled.

//////////////////////////////////Original//////////////////////////////////////

Windows will not boot now that I have installed Linux.  It starts to boot, then the computer resets before getting very far.

I decided I want Linux (I love it, even though I'm having this problem) so I installed BackTrack 5. When I installed I couldn't get the install side-by-side option so I just partitioned some memory from the HDD to add unallocated space. In the installer I used the unallocated space for the BT5 Installation. I was running BT5 and went to boot Windows and I couldn't.

I wasn't worried. I popped in the Win7 Installation Live USB I had made, and then I started to worry because the automatic repair wouldn't work and neither would the `bootrec` and `bootsect` commands.  I now have Kali 1 which is a Debian Wheezy distribution. I included the [boot-repair info](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6440641/) and a youtube video to show what happens when I try to boot Windows.

I'm about try to get a cracked copy of Windows 7 so I can run it Live off of a USB and run EasyBCD.

(I hope this doesn't get blocked for being too localized because I really need the help. I've done days of research now to try to fix my problem.)

[Edit] I'm now leaning towards a driver error because the Windows Bootloader starts and runs as seen in the YouTube video.

[Edit2] Disk part says that the hard is an invalid dynamic disk ]

Comment: You don't need to use a cracked copy of Windows 7 since you already have a license for Windows 7.  But if you are getting BSOD, which is indicated by the computer restarting, EasyBCD is not going to solve the problem.

Comment: BCOD? The cracked version was to be able to run a Live Windiws from a. USB. I think it's a driver error instead if the boot sector.

Comment: Your last comment does not make a great deal of sense.  Without the ability to repair the problem or the ability to boot into Safe Mode, you might have to by hand load the Hive and disable the problem drivers.  This will require a great deal of trial and error and you need a working Windows installation ( I will again point out an actual licensed version of Windows has the capability to become a Live CD even if its not actually supported ).

Comment: Alright. Sorry, I misunderstood the booting from a licensed version. Sorry for the post not making sense. I typed this on my phone at school and auto correct has a mind of its own.

Comment: It seems that the system is restarting the moment it hits your video-card driver. Have you tried the [Recovery Options](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-are-system-recovery-options#what-are-system-recovery-options=windows-vista) from the [boot menu](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNCJm.jpg) you get by pressing `F8`?

Comment: Yes, I have. That was the first thing I did. I even went to low resolution mode (AKA VGA mode) in hopes of it getting passed my video-card driver, but it still restarts as soon as it reaches the video-card driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The live USB version of Windows is just that, it runs from the USB so it makes sense that it would run. It is in no way tied to the Linux/Win7 installs that reside on your hard drive.

I'd be inclined to think you may have scrapped your windows 7 install when you installed Linux. If bootsect and startup repair are failing, I'd start off loading any files you want to keep that reside on the windows partition.

The easiest/quickest way to get everything working would be to start from scratch. Format the hard drive and install Linux, then install windows 7 on a separate partition. This will give you access to the boot menu to choose the OS as well. Who cares what exactly is making it not start, just bypass the issue entirely and get on with life. You been at this for days already? This method will have you up and running in under an hour.

Even if you choose to not use the method above, I would still advise backing up your files on the windows 7 partition before proceeding with any other actions. Your in a somewhat fragile area and the wrong action could result in total data loss.

Comment: I may decide to go ahead and do that. Could I possibly format the C partition instead of the entire disk and it work? I also can't read the sticker on the bottom of my laptop, so I need to find a way to get my product key.

Comment: I've just never heard of the bootable version of Windows that wasn't cracked.

Comment: You could try just formatting one partition and see how it goes. There is a good chance it will work. I'd recommend a full format just to be sure everything is right though. There are utilities floating around that can pull your product code from a Win7 install if you sticker is destroyed, but you need to get logged into Win7 first so you may be SOL on that end.

Comment: With my next pay check I might just take it down to my local computer shop. I need an external HDD to back things up. I agree though, formatting seems like the only option. Is it possible to get an OEM code and use that?

Comment: An OEM code should work as long as it is for the same type of install, ie Home, Professional, or Ultimate

Comment: Alright. Thanks. I'll talk to HP and get one.