# Remove Windows Driver from Linux

Tags: windows-7, linux, drivers, display-driver, kali-linux

I have a dual boot system with Win7 and Linux. After my install, Windows attempts to boot in safe mode but fails at a driver. It's the AMD video card driver. How do I uninstall a driver for Windows from Linux?

Comment: Does the F8 "Last Known Good Configuration" option not work to at least get you to a working system to uninstall Catalyst?

Comment: My original post: http://superuser.com/questions/677751/cant-boot-windows-after-backtrack-5-install. I can't do any of that. Here's a video of what happens : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SwyIUCtPEQc

Comment: I'm sure it's not my boot sector now.

Comment: @Drue - Be specific. What isn't in your boot sector? Its still possible to do a selective safe mode boot have you tried that?  Why exactly isn't Grub installed?  When you installed Linux it should have been installed, so your able to select which operating system you want to boot to, thats a major issue if its missing.

Comment: I do have Grub installed. I did manually repair the boot sector using a windows installation disk and the windows boot loader started up and I was able to choose the Windies OS, but it fails when it starts to load in safe mode. I've pressed F8 to make it manually go in safe mode, but it fails when I try to boot the computer.